# Programmatically checking a connection string username/password?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have a customer provided database which is configured with multiple users. Each user has their own username/password etc, which are database logins for SQL Server.

In legacy software, the user is asked for their database and password which is then used to form a connectionstring in code.

I am tasked with replacing a lot of the database code for this, and I need a way of checking a username and password against the database quite quickly. At present, using Linq, if the password is incorrect I eventually get a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` but this takes quite a while to actually throw (I assume a timeout?).

Does anybody know a good way that  I can test my username/password combo against the database quickly?

Comment: Might look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154485/how-to-test-sqlserver-connection-without-opening-a-database. Not sure if it will return quicker response if the password is incorrect though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try opening a connection through ADO, with a reduced timeout

```
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection (yourconnectionstring + ";Connection Timeout=1;");          
 try
 { 
     conn.Open();
     conn.Close();
 }
 catch (SqlException ex)
 {
     if (ex.Number == 18456)
     {
          // invalid login
     }
 }
```

18456 is SQL Invalid login

The default connection timeout is 15 seconds.

Comment: What if the DB server is busy with many connections and has to wait for some time to process this request?in that case even though the user and password are correct,it says invalid login to user.

Comment: Then it will fail. That's why the default is 15 seconds. You could put this in a loop of ever increasing timeouts, or check the exact response from the connection exception.

Comment: In my case the DB server is never really very busy, so this might work fine as a workaround to be honest. I'll put it into the test build this AM and see if it does the job.

Answer (score -1):

I would argue that you don't want the database (or anything, really) to be able to tell you that the credentials that you've passed in are incorrect. Why? Because that allows for brute force checking. Even introducing a small delay goes a long way in thwarting such attempts.